# React/Flux: strange error while rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I am getting this error while dynamically rendering a component in react

> findComponentRoot(..., .0.1.1.0.1.0.5.0.1:4): Unable to find element.
>   This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the
>   browser), usually due to forgetting a  when using tables,
>   nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an
>   <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React
>   ID

I have checked out the markup and it seems fine. Sometimes the error changes on element, I mean, sometimes it appears to affect a certain element sometimes it appears on other elements.

Here is my render object:

```
render: function(){

    var _slots = function(id, h, handleClick){

        //react way to do this
        var daysforSlot = this.props.workingDays.map(function(day, i){

            var spanActive = this.state.appointments.map(function(appointment){
                            var _activeClass = null;
                            var _s = null;

                            if(h.hour+day === appointment.hour+appointment.day){
                                _activeClass = 'active'
                            }

                            if(_activeClass){
                                _s = <span className='active'>{appointment.patient.name}</span>
                            }


                            return (  {_s}  )
            });

            return (
                <td id={h.hour+day} onClick={handleClick.bind(null, {hour: h.hour, day:i})}>
                    {spanActive}
                </td>
            )
    }.bind(this));


    return(
            <div>
                <td>{h.text}</td>
                <span>{daysforSlot}</span>
            </div>
        )

    }.bind(this);

    //creates the working hours for the days and bind the click
    //handler to the hour slots
    var _schedule = this.props.workingHours.map(function(h, i){

        return (
                <tr>
                  <span>{_slots(i, h, this.handleClick)}</span>
                </tr>
            )
    }.bind(this));

    return(
        <span>
            {_schedule}
        </span>
    )
}
```

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: It means more or less what it says on the tin. When you create a table via HTML (or React) the browser will insert `thead` and `tbody` tags in the DOM/Virtual DOM even if you do not. When you mutate your state or properties this causes there to be a mismatch between parent/child mappings tracked by React and causes this error. Be sure to output `tbody` (and `thead` when relevant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html you're outputting is invalid. You have a td directly inside of a div - they must be the direct child of tr. Also you have a span as the child of tr, which is not valid.

Comment: This answer was hugely helpful to me when I was conditionally returning an empty `div` inside a table in my `render` method in my component, which screwed up the markup.